# Data binding with Entity Framework Navigation properties using ComboBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, combobox, navigation

I am having some trouble with data binding and the Entity Framework's navigation properties.

I have two classes, generated by the Entity Framework designer:

**Class Foo**:

```
id (int)
bar (Bar)
...
```

**Class Bar**

```
id (int)
name (string)
...
```

Using an `ObservableCollection<Foo>`, I have populated a datagrid with the following columns:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=id}"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bar">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox 
                    SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                    SelectedValue=
                        "{Binding Path=bar.Id, Mode=TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="name" 
                    ItemsSource=
                        "{Binding Path=BarList, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                    Background="White" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

The ComboBox is populated with an `ObservableCollection<Bar>` and is correctly showing the current `Bar`.

The problem comes when I select another item in the combobox. I get the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source.

System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified
```

I can see why the error pops up, but how can I handle this differently?

EDIT: The relationship between `Foo` and `Bar` is N..1, meaning that a `Foo` has 1 or 0 `Bar` while a Bar can have several `Foo`s.

At the moment, I am not able to select a new `Bar` for my `Foo`s.

Comment: Hello @thakrage! What are you exactly trying to achieve here ? Changeing the id of one of your ViewModel does indeed looks problematic !

Comment: I am not using MVVM, but I want to have a combobox containing a list of Bars. From this list, I want to be able to select another Bar for my Foo. I'll edit the question

Comment: Even if you are not using MVVM, your DataGrid seems to be binded. So each of your row is generated from an underlying object (in your case, a Foo) Do you want to modify the ObservableCollection<Foo> when selecting a value in the ComboBox ? Edit: Just saw your edit : So the comboxBox is meant to allow user to select a Bar for a givent Foo ?

Comment: Excactly. The combobox is meant to allow a user to assign a new Bar to each Foo. And whenever I do this, the exception occurs.

Comment: I'll have a solution ready for you asap

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: can you please show your view model because i think the problem is not with binding the problem is may be you adding bar to foo that already has other foo ID

Comment: Did you have time to try the solution I provided ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind on the `bar` property directly. Your code tries to change the `Id` on the selected Foo's bar, but what you want is to change the bar associated to the current Foo. You also have to override `Equals` method on your `Bar` class.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding bar, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BarList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Background="White" />
```

And in your `Bar` class :

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Bar)
        return ((Bar)obj).Id == Id;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to do it using objects directly (which means not using the `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue` but instead using `SelectedItem="{Binding Foo.Bar}"` directly, you need to instruct the EF designer to `generate foreign key property BarId on the Foo entity`, then you can bind the `SelectedValue="{Binding Foo.BarId}"`.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the problem is more with Entity-Framework than with WPF. Is it correct that bar's id is at the same time part of foo's primary key? At least the binding, the setup of the ComboBox and the error message seem to imply that.

One of the limitations of entity framework is that it doesn't support key updates. If you want to change the key of an object, you basically have to delete it, recreate it with the new key, and copy all other properties. In a program I am currently working on, I decided to create a wrapper class which exposes the Id as a property and does this handling behind the scenes when it is changed. I have seen posts which suggested to just detach the object and reuse it, but in my case this didn't work.

Comment: Well there is no problem with Entity-Framework, the problem is indeed with the WPF. If you read our comments, thakrage states that he wants to change the bar associated with a Foo, his binding tries to change the Id of the bar (which indeed seems to be incorrect due to a key update restriction). It's a simple binding error.

Comment: On second thought I think you are right. I was probably misled by the error message. It all depends on the intention of the incorrect code.